# ACCDE error 3625 The text file specification 'X' does not exist

Tags: vba, ms-access, text-files, ms-access-forms

Using MS Access 2019 to deploy an **.accde** form that I developed.

It checks the value of the current form's version from a **.tab** text file that is hosted in a shared folder and imported as a linked table into the DB.

This works in the **.accdb** but in the **.accde** version throws error 3625:

> The text file specification 'X' does not exist...

Code for reading data from file (this is inside a Module):

```
Public Function checkVer()
    Dim ind As Boolean
    ind = DLookup("[ACTIVE]", "Ver", "Ver = '9'")
    If Not ind Then
        MsgBox "This version is obsolete. You may get the latest version from the shared folder."
        Application.Quit acSaveNo
    End If
End Function
```

How the function is called:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    checkVer
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated...

I tried deleting the file specifications records from the MSYSImexSpecs table, deleting the linked table and reimporting the file as a linked table again, Compact and Repair, a full decompile and tested successfully the functionality in the .accdb version of the form.

Comment: The link works - you can open as datasheet? Edit question to show code.

Comment: Code added. The linked table opens as datasheet view just fine in the .accdb.

Comment: Also, I made a mistake. the error does popup in the .accde version unlike what was stated originally. Apology.

Comment: If you can open into datasheet, should be able to query with DLookup or open a recordset. I see nothing in that code to cause the indicated error. However, if Ver is a number field, don't use apostrophe delimiters. Also, ind is declared as a Boolean and therefore cannot hold Null. If DLookup does not find a match, it will return Null and trigger run-time error.  Can handle possible Null with Nz() function: `ind = Nz(DLookup(...), False))`. I use a table in Access to hold version info.

Comment: Appreciate the Nz() tip to handle Null. Of course, it didn't address the error which is a frustrating one. What bothers me is that it works in .accdb but not when I make the .accde version! I prefer the .tab solution if the error can be figured out by someone...

Comment: I did a simple test. Built .tab file, linked, code behind button to run DLookup(), created accde. Code runs just fine. Cannot replicate issue. Your table is named Ver - same as field name?

Comment: Would you kindly put the code in a Modeul and run the code On Form Load event to match my setup? I just created another file with different file/field names, linked and tested. Got same error.

Comment: Yes, to answer your question re table & field name being the same.

Comment: Edit question to show how you call this function. Why not make it a Sub instead since function is not returning anything to calling procedure.

Comment: Edited as suggested

Comment: I did test as you asked - called function from form Load event. - accde still works. I did remove apostrophe delimiters because Ver field is set as number type.

Comment: Noted and appreciated. I reverted back to a table in the main DB and it works. May revisit this issue later by recreating from scratch. Thank you for your time and advice.

Comment: There are related records in MSysIMEXColumns left orphaned when you deleted from MSysIMEXSpecs.